# php get link herf and text if they contain set text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How do i get the herf link and the text from a link like so

```
    <a herf="google.com">boom</a>
```

i need the google.com part and the boom text only ?

also how do i filter out the links to make sure i only get the herf for the link with the text boom because the page has links like this

```
    <a herf="google.com">boom</a>
    <a herf="google.com">boom1</a>
    <a herf="google.com">boom2</a>
    <a herf="google.com">boom3</a>
```

Comment: It's `href`, not `herf`. And what does AJAX or PHP have to do with your question? Go read up on jQuery functions like .attr(), text(), and :contains.

Comment: You should show us what you've already tried, we are not here to do your job, but to help you doing it.

Comment: @j08691 i have dyslexia so sorry and i am looking for eather a ajax or php answear

lght i have a file using php to get the files html and then i have it going threw this file and grabbing all the a link that have a set text in the href but i didnt know to get the text as well

Comment: @Lght Looks too harsh.. Just ask like "can you show the script part?" :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Didn't understant how do you want to get them, but this will do the job on php http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3920bf99f02b18bc707d2699a2e37ab25879bb20

**EDIT :**

```
<?php
$str = ' <a herf="google.com">boom</a>
    <a herf="google.com">boom1</a>
    <a herf="google2.com">boom</a>
    <a herf="google.com">boom3</a>';


preg_match_all('/\<a\s[href]+\=\"([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_\?\=\#\&]+)\"\>boom\</ui',$str,$matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Please post the code, not just a link. If the site you link to is down or goes offline, your answer will not convey any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.filter()` along with its call back function to achieve your need,

```
var anchorWithSpecificText = $('a').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() == "boom";
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0gnat27f/)